# InvalidParameterValue: DatabaseName are cannot be used for aurora postgresql in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create an aurora postgresql cluster using terraform. I am getting following error after terraform apply,  **Error:** *error creating RDS cluster: InvalidParameterValue: DatabaseName are cannot be used.  It is a reserved word for this engine*

I checked the terraform docs and community module on the github and I could see the parameter **database_name** is used and seems valid.

Code snippet

```
######### Creating RDS cluster  ###########
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "db-cluster" {
  cluster_identifier      = var.cluster_identifier
  engine                  = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version          = "14.6"
  database_name           = var.database_name
}
```

I also tried using **db_name** as parameter, as it used in rds cluster but it wasn't expected here.

[image]

I am trying to create an aurora cluster for postgresql and expecting to pass name for an automatically created database on cluster creation.

```
module variable.tf,
variable "database_name" { 
description = "Name for an automatically created database on cluster creation"
type = string
default = null
}

root main.tf,
module "DataBase-Server" { ### Module for RDS-Aurora-PostgreSQL 
source = "./Modules/DB/RDS-Aurora-PostgreSQL" 
database_name = var.db_name 
aws_region = var.aws_region 
}

terraform.tfvars,
db_name = "taare"
```

Comment: What is the `database_name` value?

Comment: Can you show where you set `var.database_name`?

Comment: Based on the error, I'm guessing you set the variable `database_name` to the value of `aurora-postgresql` and that is a reserved value for the `engine` argument.

Comment: variables.tf

variable "database_name" {
  description = "Name for an automatically created database on cluster creation"
  type        = string
  default     = null
}

main.tf
module "DataBase-Server" { ###  Module for RDS-Aurora-PostgreSQL
  source                          = "./Modules/DB/RDS-Aurora-PostgreSQL"
  database_name                   = var.db_name
  aws_region                      = var.aws_region

terraform.tfvars
db_name                         = "taare"

Comment: Thank you for the responses.
I have edited the post to show where and how I am passing database_name.

Comment: You named your variable "database_name" but you try to reference and use the name "db_name", which is not the same.

Comment: I named the variable "database_name" in module variable.tf. In the root variable.tf, when calling the module, I am further naming it as database_name  = var.db_name, which I think is OK to do as it doesn't throw any error for other variables when I follow the same naming convention. Just to update that when I removed the database_name variable, it worked and cluster got created but without db obviously. Also if I follow the same naming throughout, still it didn't helped.